# Scapy on mac os 10.7.5

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

How to install scapy on my mac os lion 10.7.5 running python 2.7? How to install using easy_install in terminal? I tried using the command easy_install scapy on terminal it says the following

error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-15703.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Answer (score 1):

After `brew install scapy`,You must do as this:

 `mkdir -p /Users/yanzi/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/yanzi/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth`

Then restart your Python IDE. Note:replace "yanzi" by your own home folder name

Answer (score 0):

For your particular issue it may be as easy as putting a 'sudo' in front of the command.

```
sudo easy_install scapy
```

If that doesn't do the trick for you or you have issues with the dependencies I found Homebrew Python GitHub page https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python which contains lots of helpful/useful brew formula including one for Scapy that worked like a charm for me. Simply clone his repo and run these commands:

```
brew tap Homebrew/python
brew install scapy
```

I also had an issue with my pcapy which was solved by another formula in the repo for pypcap, so same procedure.

```
brew install pypcap
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps [here](http://juhalaaksonen.com/blog/2013/12/11/installing-scapy-for-mac-os-x/) worked for me.

So I run these commands:

```
$ wget scapy.net  
$ unzip scapy-latest.zip  
$ cd scapy-2.*  
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Then,

```
$ wget http://libdnet.googlecode.com/files/libdnet-1.12.tgz  
$ tar xfz libdnet-1.12.tgz  
$ ./configure  
$ make  
$ sudo make install  
$ cd python  
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Lastly

```
$ sudo easy_install pcapy
```

Comment: for whom runs into the the second url is now https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy (look for the zip file/download button)